# How to get real-time microphone levels with Phonegap/Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, microphone, avaudiosession

I am looking for a way to read volume data in real-time from the microphone. Just some kind of general "loudness". The purpose is to make lips move when you talk into the microphone on an html5 canvas element...

I basically want this plugin but for microphone levels instead of the camera:

https://github.com/casoninabox/luminance-cordova-ios

Does anyone know of any existing libraries to do this or how I might go about creating a plugin for iOS? I'm guessing it would involve the `AVAudioSession`?

Comment: Why don't you write your own? :)

Comment: Looks like I am going to have to.  I was just making sure I wasn't going to be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I've found a html5 solution here: https://scottizu.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/real-time-visualization-of-raw-sound-from-microphone-input-using-html5/ but I think that for cordova on iOS you'd need it to work in safari, which does not support `getUserMedia`.

Comment: Yea, that doesn't really solve my main problem of getting the real-time mic data from iOS though.  I think I need to make a plugin.  Someone made one for Android, but they didn't do iOS, maybe I'll fork it and add iOS.  I'll post whatever I do back here for future people.

Comment: How's it coming along Blankasaurus?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin, that measures volume data in decibels: https://github.com/akofman/cordova-plugin-dbmeter

Install plugin with:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dbmeter
```

Make sure that you add these lines to your app config.xml as that plugin doesn't currently support Swift 3.

```
<preference name="UseLegacySwiftLanguageVersion" value="true" />
```

Use plugin like that:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    DBMeter.start(function(dB){
        console.log(dB);
    });
}
```